# Function with variable-length argument and keyword-only arguments in Python

Tags: python, parameters, syntax, function-definition

In Python, I wanted to define a function with both a variable-length first argument, and keyword-only arguments. For instance, something like

```py
def add(*vals: int, *, negative: bool = False):
    """Compute the sum of all elements of `vals`."""
    s = 0
    for v in vals:
        s += v
    return -s if negative else s

# Desired behavior
>>> add(3, 2, -1)
4
>>> add(3, 2, -1, negative=True)
-4
>>> add(3, 2, -1, True)
TypeError: add() takes _ positional argument but _ were given
```

But trying to define this function returns the following error

```py
    def add(*vals, *, negative=False):
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this the behavior, and is there a way to work around it?

Answer (score 4):

You can directly define the function with `def add(*vals, negative=False):`.

Adding `*` is disallowed because it's impossible to set a value for `negative` without using keyword arguments: all positional arguments are swallowed by `vals`.

Comment: Alternatively, `*` is also only *required* when a starred parameter name isn't present to signal the end of the "regular" parameters.

Comment: But if I define it like that, it is allowed to run `add(3, 2, -1, True)` which then returns `5` instead of `-4`. How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: @Ronan Python is dynamically typed. There's no way to know that `True` should not be part of the positional arguments. That would be the job of a type checker to warn you about passing unexpected values. (On the other hand, `bool` is a subclass of `int`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is

`def add(*vals, negative=False):`

Answer (score 0):

In terms of *why* this results in a syntax error, that can be answered with a quick look at Python's [parameter list syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

```
parameter_list            ::=  defparameter ("," defparameter)* "," "/" ["," [parameter_list_no_posonly]]
                                 | parameter_list_no_posonly
parameter_list_no_posonly ::=  defparameter ("," defparameter)* ["," [parameter_list_starargs]]
                               | parameter_list_starargs
parameter_list_starargs   ::=  "*" [parameter] ("," defparameter)* ["," ["**" parameter [","]]]
                               | "**" parameter [","]
parameter                 ::=  identifier [":" expression]
defparameter              ::=  parameter ["=" expression]
```

There is a bit to chew through here, but the key points to note are that

- `parameter_list_starargs` may appear *only once* in a parameter list, and
- within `parameter_list_starargs`, the notation `"*" [parameter]` encompasses *both* the `*args,` and `*,` constructs. That is, both `*args,` and `*,` occupy the same place of the parameter list syntax.

Syntatically speaking, writing `*args, *,` in a parameter list is exactly the same as trying to write, say, `*args1, *args2` or `*, *,` --- it just doesn't fit into the grammer.